# Ubuntu PHP5/Apache2 - Displaying 500 error instead of error message

Tags: php, http, apache2, httpd.conf

The following script is not outputting error messages to the browser. Instead it results in an HTTP Error 500 response.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

phpinfo();

echo "test" asdf // This should error
?>
```

Ideas? This is a basic php5/apache2 install on ubuntu. httpd.conf is blank, no .htaccess file.

The error.log file displays the error message:

> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

which is correct.

Comment: Does this give you any more errors `ini_set(‘display_startup_errors’, ‘On’);`?

Comment: delete the error.log file and run it again. I suspect your php install isn't working..... if it is then the error.log file will be regenerated. the fact that your httpd.conf file is blank could be an issue too

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same problem now, any and all PHP errors cause 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

phpinfo();

echo "test" asdf // This should error
?>
```

In `error_reporting` `-1` shows even more than `E_ALL` and for `display_errors` I used the value `1` instead of `On`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Edit: I got the answer!

> If the script has a parse error that prevents it from running, this also prevents it from > changing a PHP setting.

https://serverfault.com/questions/242662/ubuntu-php5-apache2-displaying-500-error-instead-of-error-message

Comment: I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: if the script doesn't run, the php.ini changes do not get commited... see edit

Comment: Ok, I understand now... Looks like the solution is to just turn on errors via the ini file then. Thanks!